# Date not being imported from csv in proper format in MySQL

Tags: mysql, import, csv

**I am new to MySQL, so kindly explain your answers in a simple way!**

I have a csv file which has **2 date columns.** I want to import the csv into MySQL and I am using the following method:

1. Create an **empty table** in the database with **proper column types**. So both date columns were assigned a `DATE` datatype and so on.
2. Load the csv using following query:

   ```
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\Shrey\OneDrive\Desktop\assignments\Samyak\Comorbidity Covid-19.csv'  
    INTO TABLE `comorbidity` 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS;
   ```

The issue is that both **date** columns are being imported but with all the entries like `0000-00-00`.

I tried the following query as suggested by **@Ergest Basha**:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Shrey/OneDrive/Desktop/assignments/Samyak/Comorbidity Covid-19.csv'  
INTO TABLE `comorbidity`  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS

( 
@Current_date_var, @Start_Date_var, State, 
Condition_group, `Condition`, 
Age_group, Covid19_deaths, Number_of_mentions
)
SET `Date_as_of` = STR_TO_DATE(@Current_date_var,  '%m-%d-%Y') ,
  Start_date = STR_TO_DATE(@Start_Date_var,  '%m-%d-%Y')
;
```

But still get the same output!

This is a sample of the data I am working with:-

| Date as of | Start date | State | Condition group | Condition | Age group | Covid-19 deaths | Number of mentions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02-06-2022 | 01-01-2020 | United States | Respiratory diseases | Influenza | 0-24 | 1167 | 1127 |
| 02-06-2022 | 01-01-2020 | United States | Respiratory disease | pneumonia | 25-51 | 2254 | 5458 |
| 02-06-2022 | 02-02-2020 | United States | Respiratory disease | pneumonia | 52-76 | 5545 | 2222 |

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Yes Condition is a reserved word but it is also the name of one of my columns. That is why I have included it in the column list along with other column names!

Comment: Using reserved word (and even keyword) as object name is wrong practice. I strongly recommend you to rename this column.

Answer (score 4):

First your query contains [MySQL Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)  `Condition` and `Current_date` please  avoid using reserved words.  and secondly you are using `SET` twice.

Try:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\Shrey\OneDrive\Desktop\assignments\Samyak\Comorbidity Covid-19.csv'  
INTO TABLE `comorbidity` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@Current_date_var, @Start_Date_var, State, Condition_Group, `Condition`, Age_group, Covid19_deaths, Number_of_mentions)
SET `Current_date` = STR_TO_DATE(@Current_date_var,  '%m-%d-%Y') ,
    Start_Date = STR_TO_DATE(@Start_Date_var,  '%m-%d-%Y')
;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1850517047b1e27ca4c4f5ed73e81414)

Be aware that `STR_TO_DATE(@Current_date_var,  '%m-%d-%Y')` returns the date in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format, so you should have a date type column.

For example:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('02-21-2022',  '%m-%d-%Y');
```

Returns:

```
STR_TO_DATE('02-21-2022',  '%m-%d-%Y')
2022-02-21
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=481b7be3a0cc6056668870921d30bd7c)

Example with the updated data:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `comorbidity` (
  `State` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Condition_Group` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Condition` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    ->   `Current_date` date NOT NULL,
    ->   `Start_Date` date NOT NULL,
    ->   `State` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    ->   `Condition_Group` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ->   `Condition` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    ->   `Age_group` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    ->   `Covid19_deaths` int NOT NULL,
    ->   `Number_of_mentions` int NOT NULL
    -> ) ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.57 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%secure%';
+--------------------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                 |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+
| require_secure_transport | OFF                   |
| secure_file_priv         | /var/lib/mysql-files/ |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/comorbidity.csv'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@Current_date_var, @Start_Date_var, State, Condition_Group, `Condition`, Age_group, Covid19_deaths, Number_of_mentions)
SET `Current_date` = STR_TO_DATE(@Current_date_var,  '%m-%d-%Y') ,
    Start_Date = STR_TO_DATE(@Start_Date_var,  '%m-%d-%Y')
;

    -> IGNORE INTO TABLE `comorbidity`
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> IGNORE 1 ROWS
    -> (@Current_date_var, @Start_Date_var, State, Condition_Group, `Condition`, Age_group, Covid19_deaths, Number_of_mentions)
    -> SET `Current_date` = STR_TO_DATE(@Current_date_var,  '%m-%d-%Y') ,
    ->     Start_Date = STR_TO_DATE(@Start_Date_var,  '%m-%d-%Y')
    -> ;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> select * from comorbidity;
+--------------+------------+---------------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------+
| Current_date | Start_Date | State         | Condition_Group      | Condition | Age_group | Covid19_deaths | Number_of_mentions |
+--------------+------------+---------------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------+
| 2022-02-06   | 2020-01-01 | United States | Respiratory diseases | Influenza | 0-24      |           1167 |               1127 |
| 2022-02-06   | 2020-01-01 | United States | Respiratory disease  | pneumonia | 25-51     |           2254 |               5458 |
| 2022-02-06   | 2020-02-02 | United States | Respiratory disease  | pneumonia | 52-76     |           5545 |               2222 |
+--------------+------------+---------------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This gives me following error : `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Current_date = STR_TO_DATE(@Current_date_var,  '%m-%d-%Y') ,     Start_Date = ST' at line 8`. I am getting this error. I made sure both the date column are of DATE type too!

Comment: Ok that error is solved and the records are being imported. But still the date columns are in the `0000-00-00` format

Comment: Added some rows

Comment: Still no luck! I have literally copy pasted the same code and still no luck. I have updated my question with your code (the second code in the question is what I tried)

Comment: Another problem with using only `\n` is that some of my column values are long. So If I use only `\n` then half the text goes into another columns. Basically it messes up my table!